# html target iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In the following code after submitting the form I need to stay on the same page so I say my target is iframe.

But after I get the response I need to populate a text area how can I do it. What's wrong with the code below?

```
<script>
    //After I get a response
    $("#result").html("This is your result"); //Textarea not populated
</script>

<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contentform" action="/dg/execute_model/" target="upload_target" onsubmit="return validate();">{% csrf_token %}
    <b>
        <table class="cat-tab" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><font>*</font>Test data</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="test_file" id="test_file" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Build" id="addbtn" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>

<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;">
    <b><br>Result:<br><br></b>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="result" id="result" ></textarea>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't target an iFrame. Maybe try to use jQuery Load to load the content into a div

Comment: @Rajeev You seem to have a perfect acceptance record so far. Has no answer satisfied your needs?

Answer (score 2):

**Why querying `$('#result')` doesn't work in your example**

By default jQuery queries the DOM tree of the current `document` object. As the `iframe` element in effect embeds a separate `window` object with a separate `document` object, the textarea is simply not in the scope of your current query and is not found.

**How to query `$('#result')` correctly**

This means that in order to traverse the DOM embedded by the `iframe` we first need to access the iframe's `window` and `document` objects. A safe and cross-browser way to do that is to access the iframe's `window` with its `.contentWindow` property, followed by the `.document` property of the `window`.

For example:

```
var target_document = $('#upload_target')[0].contentWindow.document;
var target_result   = $(target_document).find('#result');
target_result.val('This is your result');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
$('#upload_target').contents().find('#result').html('This is your result');
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$( "#result", $("#upload_target").contents() ).val("This is your result.");
```